# Session timeout Android

Tags: android, session-timeout, android-dialog

My android app has a main login screen and various screens which follow. I want to create a session timeout dialog which shows up when:
1) the user is on any page except the login page and 2) the user has not interacted with the application for 5 minutes.

The session timeout dialog should have a logout button which takes the user back to the login screen. How do I do this?

Comment: _the user has not interacted with the application for 5 minutes_ for this you can use `Timer` , `CountDownTimer` etc etc. Many options. You need to save your time in shared preference

Answer (score 1):

Do this

Get the time stamp when ever user interacts with the app. Compare it with previous time stamp and get the difference.

Now if difference is more than 5min, prompt a dialog with logout button.

Comment: which class do I put this in?

Comment: in the parent class so that time stamp can be recorded for all the classes which inherit that parent